# Remove Value in Sharedprefenreces

Tags: flutter, dart

I noticed that in sharedprefrences you can remove a key but not a value.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.remove(key);
```

How can i remove a  value?

Comment: set the key value to null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow,
from the documentation of the package on pub.dev I can see that you might have understood the method's intention:

1 - Using the `remove` method removes both the key and the value, and you can set the key later with another value, that works perfectly.

2- Alternatively as 'MyNameIs' pointed out, you can set the key's value with null.

please also note that you can clear all of SharedPreferences' data using the `clear` method.

You can refer to the documentation of the SharedPreferences class from here: 
https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences/latest/shared_preferences/SharedPreferences-class.html